# Funnel Visualisation not showing drop out in steps

Tags: google-analytics

I have a site where users will follow this path (hopefully):

`mysite.com/entity`
`mysite.com/entity/pay`
`mysite.com/entity/pay/details`
`mysite.com/entity/pay/confirmation`
`mysite.com/entity/pay/payment`
`mysite.com/entity/paymentsuccessful?lotsofuniquestuff`

The `entity` section could be any one of a multitude of entries, but once the user is on a journey it will stay consistent.

I have a goal set up for this as a regular expression, with the match being `.*PaymentSuccessful.*`.  This detects goal successes perfectly (as checked with data stored by the site directly).

I have set the following steps within the goal:

```
/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/pay
/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/pay/details
/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/pay/confirmation
/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/pay/payment
```

My funnel detects entry into the funnel (e.g. 47 users) of which say 10 complete the funnel.

However, all drop offs are after the first step, even though the exist page is listed as the second step!  My data also suggests users are getting further in the funnel before failing to reach the goal.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following this advice: http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2008/06/25/funnel-problems-google-analytics/ I found that my steps were inclusive of each other due to the regex passing.  It was fixed by changing the steps to be this:

```
/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/pay$
/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/pay/details
/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/pay/confirmation
/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/pay/payment
```